# Determine number of Bytes in ByteBuffer

Tags: java, size, byte, bytebuffer

I have a `ByteBuffer` that can hold a maximum of (4 + `size`) `bytes` (that is, an integer followed by `size` characters). However, the number of characters written to the `ByteBuffer` , may be smaller than `size`.

So I was wondering, is there anyway to determine how many characters were written to the `ByteBuffer` and not just the total size of it? `limit`, `position` and such don't SEEM to be what I am after.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What about `hasRemaining`?

Comment: `hasRemaining` returns a boolean indicating if there is anything remaining, not how many bytes are remaining.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

After you've written to the ByteBuffer, the number of bytes you've written can be found with the `position()` method.

If you then `flip()` the buffer, the number of bytes in the buffer can be found with the `limit()` or `remaining()` methods.

If you then read some of the buffer, the number of bytes remaining can be found with the `remaining()` method.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Perhaps the issue is that I used `wrap` to copy a `byte[]` to the buffer? Is that messing with my use of the functions you mentioned? If so, is there a way I could read the ACTUAL number of bytes written to the `byte[]`? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Girl You cannot know the actual number of bytes written, since `ByteBuffer` is essentially "seekable". What is your write pattern? Do you use only absolute read/write methods, relative read/write methods?

Comment: @fge I am essentially reading from a `DatagrampPacket`. I know that the MAX size of the contents within the `DatagramPacket` will be `4 + size`. However, it is possible that the number of characters after the `int` could have been less than `size`. So I am just trying to determine how many characters were actually in the `DatagramPacket`. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @Giri `DatagramPacket` has `.getOffset()`, `.getLength()`, and the javadoc seems to indicate that the length of the actual received data is `.getLength() - .getOffset() + 1`; you can just wrap this using `.getData()` and this information, or is there something else?

Comment: @fge I'm not sure if this is what you meant: `byte[] buffer = new byte[4 + size];`  `DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 4 + size);`  `receiver_Socket.receive(request);`  `int length = request.getLength() - request.getOffset() + 1;` The result of this is `length` = 20 as `size` was 15. That is, `request.getOffset()` is equating to 0. In this packet I deliberately sent less than `size` characters. Sorry this is a bit messy...

Comment: An alternative would be to maybe just include the number of characters in the packet when I send it over by adding an extra `int`..?

Comment: @Giri - Sorry for the delay. As fge notes, ByteBuffer is seekable, with the position(int) method. However, you likely control whether and when this occurs, and can factor this into consideration. If the position doesn't start at 0, you could get the position before writing to the buffer, and get the position after writing, and subtract the former from the latter.

Answer (score 3):

```
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(5+size);
channel.receive(bb);
bb.flip();
// actual length of received packet
int len = bb.remaining();
```