# How can I get size of blob column of cassandra using user defined functions?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0

I was trying

```
cqlsh:my_keyspace>  CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS len(input blob) 

CALLED ON NULL INPUT

RETURNS int LANGUAGE java AS '

return input.length();';
```

Error:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Java source compilation failed:
Line 2: The method length() is undefined for the type ByteBuffer
```

if I change input to text it is working..is there anything defined for bytebuffer type ? I need to find length of blob column from table..

is there any way to find out it either in cassandra spark or by any tool ?
I am new to cassandra world please help me out for this..

Answer (score 3):

Under the hood, Cassandra uses the `ByteBuffer` Java type for its `blob` data type. This type that doesn't have the `length` method, so you need to use either `position`, or `remaining` to determine how much data in the buffer ([depending on what you're doing with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879078/determine-number-of-bytes-in-bytebuffer)).

This function works fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION blen (b blob) 
   CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
   RETURNS int 
   LANGUAGE java AS 'if (b == null) return 0; else return b.remaining();';
```